# Black color for a style font clips through original line

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

the purpose of `shadow()` is to create a line where a color that the user picks is followed by a black line. However, when the user drags the line across the canvas, particularly from right to left, the black line stutters over the original color

I implemented the same method used to create a line on canvas to create the trailing black line in `shadow()`, only changing the properties `shadowOffset`, `lineJoin`, and `lineCap` in order to create the black line effect.

```css
#c {
  border: 1px solid black;

table{
    float:left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Canvas</title>
  <link href="canvas.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
   <h2>STYLES:</h2>
    <form>
    <input type="button" value="shadow" onclick="shadow()">
    </form>

    <canvas id="c"></canvas>
</body>

<script src="canvas.js"></script>
<script src="colors.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</html>
```

```
const c = document.querySelector("#c");
c.height = window.innerHeight;
c.width = window.innerWidth;
const ctx = c.getContext("2d");
//default settings
ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
ctx.lineWidth = 15;

let confirmButton = document.querySelector(".confirm");

window.addEventListener('load', () => {


  let painting = false;

  //when mouse is clicked; paint
  function mousedown(b) {
    painting = true;
    //allows for paint to appear without nedding to drag mouse
    mousemove(b);
  }
  //when mouse is not clicked; don't paint
  function mouseup() {
    painting = false;
    //resets path each time so multiple can be created
    ctx.beginPath();
  }

  function mousemove(b) {
    //Get correct mouse position
    var pos = getMousePos(c, b);
    //if not holding down the mouse; nothing happens
    if (!painting) return;
    //roundness of paint
    ctx.lineCap = 'round';

    //create paint wherever the mouse goes: ctx[on the canvas].lineTo[move the line to]()
    ctx.lineTo(pos.x, pos.y);
    //end the stroke and visualize paint
    ctx.stroke();
    //begins a new paint so that everything doesn't just stick to a fat line
    ctx.beginPath();
    //move the new line to wherever the mouse goes
    ctx.moveTo(pos.x, pos.y);
  }

  //starting posistion of paint line
  c.addEventListener('mousedown', mousedown);
  //ending posistion of paint line
  c.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseup);
  //whenever the mouse is moving; paint 
  c.addEventListener('mousemove', mousemove);

  confirmButton.addEventListener('click', size);
});

function size() {
   numS = document.getElementById("sizeInput").value;
  ctx.lineWidth = numS;
  console.log("blah "+ ctx.lineWidth)
}


function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
  var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {
    x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
    y: evt.clientY - rect.top
  };
}

function shadow(){ 

  let sc =  ctx.shadowColor = 'rgb(0, 0, 0)';   

  let painting = false;

  //when mouse is clicked; paint
  function mousedown(b) {
    painting = true;
    sc = true;
    //allows for paint to appear without nedding to drag mouse
    mousemove(b);
  }
  //when mouse is not clicked; don't paint
  function mouseup() {
    painting = false;
    sc = false;
    //resets path each time so multiple can be created
    ctx.beginPath();
  }

  function mousemove(b) {
    //Get correct mouse position
    var pos = getMousePos(c, b);
    //if not holding down the mouse; nothing happens
    if (!painting) return;
    ctx.lineJoin = "round";
    ctx.lineCap = "round";
    ctx.shadowOffsetX = 10;
    ctx.shadowOffsetY = 10;

    //create paint wherever the mouse goes: ctx[on the canvas].lineTo[move the line to]()
    ctx.lineTo(pos.x, pos.y,);
    //end the stroke and visualize paint
    ctx.stroke();
    //begins a new paint so that everything doesn't just stick to a fat line
    ctx.beginPath();
    //move the new line to wherever the mouse goes
    ctx.moveTo(pos.x, pos.y,);
  }

  //starting posistion of paint line
  c.addEventListener('mousedown', mousedown);
  //ending posistion of paint line
  c.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseup);
  //whenever the mouse is moving; paint 
  c.addEventListener('mousemove', mousemove);
}
```

What occurs is that the trailing black line clips through the original color line, creating a stutter effect. I showed code only relevant to this question, but for clarity I have re-created the project on plunker:
https://plnkr.co/edit/0gP32ZSf0ZlOVguTj51X?p=preview

file `color.js` is not relevant to this question

Comment: Can you create a smaller code example just drawing to the canvas that reproduces this issue?

Comment: I have edited the plunker link to only display relevant information. In hindsight it was silly of me to add all that clutter.

Comment: That is a good start, but your `canvas.js` still huge reduce that too

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. `<script>` tags are to be within the body or the head only. Yours is outside the body element.

Answer (score 0):

You have a mess of functions on your `canvas.js` I could not figure out what your are doing there...
Here is a simple canvas with a shadow button

```js
const c = document.querySelector("#c");
const ctx = c.getContext("2d");

ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
ctx.lineWidth = 6;

window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  function mousemove(b) {
    var pos = getMousePos(c, b);
    ctx.lineTo(pos.x, pos.y);
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,c.width,c.height);
    ctx.stroke();
  }

  c.addEventListener('mousemove', mousemove);
});


function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
  var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {
    x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
    y: evt.clientY - rect.top
  };
}

function shadow() {
  ctx.shadowBlur = 2;
  ctx.shadowOffsetX = 6
  ctx.shadowColor = 'black';
}
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas><br>
<input type="button" value="shadow" onclick="shadow()">
```

Comment: clear your canvas or start a new sub-path before each `stroke()`. Avoid drawing in mousemove events, call stroke only in painting frames.

Comment: @Kaiido Can you explain why clear the canvas before `stroke` and how to call it from painting frames?

Comment: Because here you are drawing from the first point to the last one every single time the mousemove event fires. Just look at how you have jagged lines. That's because what should normally be antialiasing transparency gets stacked in a solid color. And to draw only in drawing frames, throttle your drawing operation from the mousemove event: https://jsfiddle.net/jdv7w4nq/

Comment: @Kaiido Thanks nice explanation! to my untrained eye this was all the same